# How can ı get the back I tried but I have error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 CREATE TABLE table_orjinal as select 1 a,2 b from dual

select * from table_orjinal


CREATE TABLE table_backup as select * from table_orjinal where 1=2;

select * from table_backup


CREATE or REPLACE trigger t_backup
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON table_orjinal
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE 
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN

    INSERT INTO table_backup (a,b) VALUES (:NEW.a,:NEW.b);  

  ELSIF DELETING THEN

    DELETE FROM table_backup WHERE a =:old.a and b =: old.b;

  ELSIF UPDATING THEN

    UPDATE table_backup 
    SET a =:new.a WHERE a =:old.a and b =: old.b;
  END IF;
END;
```

> OUTPUT
>
> Errors: TRIGGER T_BACKUP
>
> Line/Col: 4/5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Line/Col: 4/17 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> Line/Col: 8/5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Line/Col: 8/17 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
>
> Line/Col: 12/5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Line/Col: 12/12 PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
WHERE a =:old.a and b := old.b
```

The semicolons are in wrong place. You need it like this

```
WHERE a =:old.a and b = :old.b
```

Comment: oh sorry, but  errors is continue by the way thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have typos.   The errors tell you where too...

```
 INSERT INTO table_backup (a,b) VALUES (:NEW.a,NEW.b);
```

has a missing `:` and should be

```
 INSERT INTO table_backup (a,b) VALUES (:NEW.a, :NEW.b);
```

and both instances of

```
WHERE a =:old.a and b := old.b;
```

have the = and : the wrong way around and should be

```
WHERE a = :old.a and b = :old.b;
```

Comment: I fixed semicolons but error is continue thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have added few semicolons to some of your lines.I believe it will provide you less no. of errors. You can debug more ,once your no. of errors are reduced

```
 CREATE TABLE table_orjinal as select 1 a,2 b from dual;

select * from table_orjinal;


CREATE TABLE table_backup as select * from table_orjinal where 1=2;

select * from table_backup;


CREATE or REPLACE trigger t_backup
BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON table_orjinal
FOR EACH ROW
ENABLE 
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN

    INSERT INTO table_backup (a,b) VALUES (:NEW.a,NEW.b);  

  ELSIF DELETING THEN

    DELETE FROM table_backup WHERE a =:old.a and b := old.b;

  ELSIF UPDATING THEN

    UPDATE table_backup 
    SET a =:new.a WHERE a =:old.a and b := old.b;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: When you see such cases , instead of running all SQL statements at once, run 1 by 1...so that you can see from which lines errors are coming..helps to debug easily